# You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate - even though I am using Google Play Signing

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, google-play-console, android-signing

Preface: There have been many questions on Stack Overflow about this issue, but my question is unique, because it involves Google Play Signing.

I used Google Play Signing to release my app. As such, I have never created a keystore (`.jks`) file (at least for this app). I imagined Google Play Signing would take care of all that for me.

After switching to Linux, from Windows, I tried to release a new update for my app. However, I got the error mentioned in the title.

Here is my project's one and only signing config (the path was different on windows - but it still lead to the debug keystore). I've never created any others.

```
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword 'android'
        storeFile file('/home/vedantroy/.android/debug.keystore')
        storePassword 'android'
    }
}
```

What could be the issue? Is there anyway I can continue publishing updates to the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I used Google Play Signing to release my app. As such, I have never
>   created a keystore (.jks) file (at least for this app).

Even though Google Play owns the release key of your app, you still had to sign the APK you uploaded to the Play Console. This is a requirement. You possibly signed with a key auto-generated by your IDE without realising it. This is what Play Console calls the "upload key". Google Play then ensures that every future APK upload is signed with the same key.

It seems that you haven't kept the keystore you used for your first upload when changing computer, but with Google Play signing you can fortunately reset the upload key. See [Create a new upload key](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

With Google Play Signing you still sign your App with an upload key that must be the same each time. This signature is then checked and replaced by Google. It is possible to change the upload key in case you have lost it, check the Google Signing site for more info on that.